# Sql query to get Expected output

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, left-join

I have three tables named device_table, playlist_table and device_playlist_assoc

The device_playlist_assoc table is used to associate the device with the playlist.

**device_table**

| device_id | device_name |
| --- | --- |
| d1 | device1 |
| d2 | device2 |
| d3 | device3 |
| d4 | device4 |
| d5 | device5 |
| d6 | device6 |

**playlist_table**

| playlist_id | playlist_name |
| --- | --- |
| p1 | playlist1 |
| p2 | playlist2 |
| p3 | playlist3 |

**device_playlist_assoc**

| dpa_id | dpa_device_id | dpa_playlist_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | d1 | p1 |
| 2 | d1 | p2 |
| 3 | d2 | p1 |
| 4 | d2 | p3 |
| 5 | d3 | p4 |
| 6 | d4 | p5 |

So, O/P I want is to have those devices that don't have the **playlist1**. I only get playlist_id from the frontend as a parameter. So i want an sql query that can give me expected output based on this playlist_id only. i.e  whatever playlist_id i get from frontend, i should be able to get the device_id of devices that dont contain that playlist + those devices also that doesnot contain any playlist.

**Expected O/P**

| device_id |
| --- |
| d3 |
| d4 |
| d5 |
| d6 |

I tried with left outer join but i was not getting expected o/p. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it:

```
select * 
from device_table
where device_id not in (select device_id 
                        from device_playlist_assoc
                        where playlist_id = 1)
```

Comment: Answer does not match table examples above especially in the subquery.  (Select dpa_device_id from device_playlist_assoc Where dpa_playlist_id='p1')

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select d.*
from device_table d
where not exists (select 1
                  from device_playlist_assoc dp
                  where dp.dpa_device_id = d.device_id and
                        dp.dpa_playlist_id = ?
                 );
```

The `?` is a parameter placeholder for the id passed in from the application code.

I prefer `not exists` over `not in` for two reasons:

1. It behaves as you would expect if the subquery returns `NULL` values.
2. It is easy to optimize using indexes (in this case on `device_playlist_assoc(dpa_device_id, dpa_playlist_id)`.

I would speculate, though, that you might want to refer to the playlist by name and not by id.  If that is the case, you can use a `join` in the subquery:

```
select d.*
from device_table d
where not exists (select 1
                  from device_playlist_assoc dp join
                       playlist_table p
                       on dp.dpa_playlist_id = p.playlist_id
                  where dp.dpa_device_id = d.device_id and
                        p.playlist_name  = ?
                 );
```

In this case, the `?` is a parameter placeholder for the name, rather than the `id`.